# Python Flask-WTF - use same form template for add and edit operations

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm just getting started with Flask / Flask-WTF / SQLAlchemy, and most example CRUD code I see shows separate templates for adding / editing. It seems repetitive to have two templates with almost identical form html (e.g. books_add.html, books_edit.html). Conceptually it makes more sense to me to have one template, something like "books_form.html", and just call render_template on that same template from two separate route definitions. I'm not quite sure how to accomplish it though, something like:

```
@app.route('/books/add')
def add_book():
...
render_template('books_form.html', action = 'add')


@app.route('/books/edit/<id>')
def edit_book(id):
...
render_template('books_form.html', action = 'edit', id = id)
```

but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, or deviating from best practice. Any input is appreciated - specific thoughts on how to handle the single template file to deal with either add or edit behavior. Links to examples are welcome as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to have separate templates for adding / editing different kinds of *things* even.  Consider:

```
{# data.html #}
<!-- ... snip ... -->
{% block form %}
<section>
<h1>{{ action }} {{ data_type }}</h1>
<form action="{{ form_action }}" method="{{ method | d("POST") }}">
{% render_form(form) %}
</form>
</section>
{% endblock form %}
```

Ignore the macro `render_form` works (there's an example one in WTForms' documentation) - it just takes a WTForms-type object and renders the form in an unordered list.  You can then do this:

```
@app.route("/books/")
def add_book():
    form = BookForm()
    # ... snip ...
    return render_template("data.html", action="Add", data_type="a book", form=form)

@app.route("/books/<int:book_id>")
def edit_book(book_id):
    book = lookup_book_by_id(book_id)
    form = BookForm(obj=book)
    # ... snip ...
    return render_template("data.html", data_type=book.title, action="Edit", form=form)
```

But you don't need to limit yourself to just books:

```
@app.route("/a-resource/")
def add_resource():
    # ... snip ...
    return render_template("data.html", data_type="a resource" ...)

# ... etc. ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I understand the reference to render_form - I went back to WTForms documentation and Quickstart, couldn't find it. I can't get it to work in my code. I get where you're going - you've abstracted your form template even more than I was thinking, which I like. Maybe if you can elaborate a bit more on that particular piece?

Comment: You can use a jinja macro to render your form. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Teisman/5653607) - most of the code you'll see there isn't mine. The `render` function is just a very generic form renderer. Like Sean indicated, if you follow this route you'll need to pass the form instance to the template.

Comment: Thanks! that helps to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I tried to overcome this issue was to not include the `SubmitField` in the form (**BookForm**). We can pass the form submit value as variable to the form, e.g `submit='Update'` in the **edit_book** route and `submit='Add Book'`.

In the route, populate the fields with the details related to the book if the post method is 'GET'