# "form.populate_by returns" ERROR:'list' object has no attribute

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am creating a view function to edit the database using a wtform, I want to populate the form with information held on the database supplied by a differente form, My problem is the query that provides the details

I have read the manual https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/crash_course.html
and the following question [Python Flask-WTF - use same form template for add and edit operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752963/python-flask-wtf-use-same-form-template-for-add-and-edit-operations)
but my query does not seem to supply the correct format of data

datatbase model:

```
class Sensors(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sensorID = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True)
```

form model:

```
class AddSensorForm(FlaskForm):
    sensorID = StringField('sensorID', validators=[DataRequired()])
    sensorName = StringField('sensorName', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')
```

view function:

```
@bp.route('/sensors/editsensor/<int:id>', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def editsensor(id):
    edit = [(s.sensorID, s.sensorName) for s in db.session.\
      query(Sensors).filter_by(id=id).all()]
    form = AddSensorForm(obj=edit)
    form.populate_obj(edit)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        sensors = Sensors(sensorID=form.sensorID.data, sensorName=form.sensorNa$
        db.session.add(sensors)
        db.session.commit()
```

shell code for query:

```
from homeHeating import db
from homeHeating import create_app
app = create_app()
app.app_context().push()
def editsensor(id):
    edit = [(s.sensorID, s.sensorName) for s in db.session.query(Sensors).filter_by(id=id).all()]
    print(edit)

editsensor(1)
[('28-0000045680fde', 'Boiler input')]
```

I expect that the two form fields will be populated with the in formation concerning the sensor called by its 'id'
but I get this error

```
File "/home/pi/heating/homeHeating/sensors/sensors.py", line 60, in 
editsensor
form.populate_obj(edit)
File "/home/pi/heating/venv/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/wtforms/form.py", line 96, in populate_obj
Open an interactive python shell in this 
framefield.populate_obj(obj, name)
File "/home/pi/heating/venv/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 330, in populate_obj
setattr(obj, name, self.data)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sensorID'
```

The error indicates that it wants 2 parts for each field "framefield.populate_obj(obj, name) mine provides only one the column data but not the column name, "sensorID"
If i hash # out the line "edit = ..." then there are no error messages and the form is returned but the fields are empty. So I want the form to be returned with the information in the database, filled in so that i can modify the name or the sensorID and then update the database.

I hope that this is clear

Warm regards

paul.

ps I have followed the instruction so the ERROR statement is only the part after "field.populate_by".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a 1-item list to your form.

Typically, when you are selecting a single record based on the primary key of your model, use Query.get() instead of Query.filter(...).all()[0].

Furthermore, you need to pass the request data to your form to validate it on submit, and also to pre-fill the fields when the form reports errors.

Form.validate_on_submit will be return True only if your request method is POST and your form passes validation; it is the step where your form tells you "the user provided syntactically correct information, now you may do more checks and I may populate an existing object with the data provided to me".

You also need to handle cases where the form is being displayed to the user for the first time.

```
@bp.route('/sensors/editsensor/<int:id>', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def editsensor(id):
    obj = Sensors.query.get(id) or Sensors()
    form = AddSensorForm(request.form, obj=obj)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.populate_obj(obj)
        db.session.add(obj)
        db.session.commit()

        # return response or redirect here
        return redirect(...)

    else:
        # either the form has errors, or the user is displaying it for
        # the first time (GET)

        return render_template('sensors.html', form=form, obj=obj)
```

Comment: You may easily change this "Edit sensor view" to a generic "create or edit sensor view" by handling cases where `get(id)` returns nothing, by creating a fresh instance of Sensors. `obj = Sensors.query.get(id) or Sensors()`

Comment: IT WORKS! IT WORKS Thank you so much,  Thank you so much for taking a look at my question. AND HELPING ME!!!!!

Comment: You are very much welcome! If this answer was useful, please vote it up and/or accept it as an answer.

Comment: Oh, forgot to add, Flask-SQLAlchemy provides a get_or_404(id) method that raises a 404 exception when an object is not found, aborting the request and displaying the 404 page.